# Can anyone simplify this python (Jupyterlab) code?

Tags: python

I'm learning from IBM skill dev. and I don't understand why they makes it so complex(for ex: using if not, why did they use if not?).
I understand they write the xlxs data into airport_data but there must be some easy way. can anyone explain?

code:

```
if not os.path.isfile("./Airport_Data.xlsx"):
    r = requests.get("https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/analysing-spreadsheet-data-with-python/Airport_Data.xlsx")
    f = open("./Airport_Data.xlsx", mode = "wb+")
    f.write(r.content)
    f.close()
```

Comment: "Things should be as simple as possible, but no simpler." How would you check if a file does not exist other than by using `if not`? Anyway, Stack Overflow is for _specific_ questions about _concrete_ programming problems; your question might be more suitable for [codereview.se]

Comment: last qns : Why would i need to check if the data exist or not, why cant i simply download the data using the link and import it is using pd.read_xlsx(Airport_Data)

Comment: It's not impossible, but that way you will need to download the same bytes every time you run the program. Having a copy saved locally saves bandwidth and spares the remote server from unnecessary traffic.

Answer (score 1):

```
'Checking if the file exists already, if it dosent go forward'
if not os.path.isfile("./Airport_Data.xlsx"): 

'Creating a get Request from the url where the data is'
r = requests.get("https:'cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/analysing-spreadsheet-data-with- python/Airport_Data.xlsx") 

'Open-Create the file in wb+ mode'
f = open("./Airport_Data.xlsx", mode = "wb+") 

'Write Data and close the file'
f.write(r.content) 
f.close()
```

It seems like it's for checking if the file already Exists, in that case it wouldn't be neccesary to download it. I scrambled the syntax a bit to make it easier to see whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified code:

```py
with requests.get("https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/analysing-spreadsheet-data-with-python/Airport_Data.xlsx") as r:
    df = pd.read_excel(r.content)
```

Comment: I understand the context of the code. I asking if there is any simpler way to obtain the similar result? or if the entire code is necessary? then how?